# What to daven when coming into minyan during Shema

Tags: tefilla

Where are you supposed to start at when you come into shachrit during shema on a regular week day?

Answer (score 2):

One should say *Netilas Yadayim, Asher Yatzar and Elokai Neshamah*, (Skip the others and say them after tefillah) then say *Birchos HaTorah* if you have not said it yet. Say *Baruch Sheamar, Ashrei, Yishtabach, Birchot krias Shema* with *Shema*. All this skipping in order to make *tefilla* with the tzibbur by saying the *amidah* with the *sheliach tzibbur* (since he is too late to catch up with the *tzibbur* itself. Although the permission to skip is usually in order to pray with the silent *amidah*, the same reasoning applies to this case. (*Psak* from Rav Chaim Kanievsky). After *Tefilla* be sure to say the *Berachos* you skipped as well as *korbanos*. One may say the parts of *pesukei di'zimrah* he skipped if he desires.

For Sefardim: One should say all *birchot haShahar* first, no matter what. (Kaf HaChayim)
The psak for sefaradim is like the *Mechaber* who says that one may **skip *Pisukei Dizimrah*** in order to make *Tefillah BiTzibbur*.

Tzibbur=Congregation
Amidah=silent devotion

(Based on Shulchan Aruch, Mishnah Berurah, Kaf Hachayim, and oral tradition.)

Answer (score 2):

Prior to davening Krias Shema (its blessings) and the Shemoneh Esrei one needs to recite "Al netilas Yadayim", "Asher Yatzar" (since one is obligated to cleans one hands and system prior to prayer), "Birchas Ha Torah", and  "Eloqai Neshama" (See MB. 52:9). Assuming these have all been said prior to arrival at Shul the Mechaber in the Shulchan Aruch (52:1) rules that if one will not be able to recite Shemoneh Esrei with the Tzibbur (congregation) then one may omit Pesukei D'Zimra and begin at the blessing for the Shema.

The Mishneh Berurah 52:1, however, cites the Sha'arei Teshuvah that one may omit [sections of] Pesukei D'Zimra *provided that one is still able to recite Baruch SheOmar, Ashrei, and Yistabach*  [the essential components of Pesukei D'Zimra].

The Mishneh Berurah 52:7 says explicitly that if one will not be able to recite the Shemoneh Esrei with the Tzibbur by beggining at the first blessing of the Krias Shema then according to everyone one should pray Pesukei D'Zimra etc. in order rather than with the Tzibbur.

Excluding those prayers which cannot be made up (such as Baruch Sh'Omar and Yishtabach, which we have noted the MB says should be recited before anyways) one should recite that which was omitted following davening Shemoneh Esrei with the tzibbur.

Comment: Rav Chaim Kanievsky says that the rational of skipping parts of psukei dizimra in order to make Tefillah bitzibbur applies even to making the bidiavad tefillah bitzibbur of saying it along with the shaliach tzibbur. Also remeber that the question was if someone comes and they are already at Shemah. There is no way for him to make the silent amidah with the tzibbur. According to Rav Chaim if skipping those parts of PD will allow him to say the amidah with the ST then he should do so.

Answer (score 1):

The usual morning brachos [if you are Sefaradi].

Comment: Huh? Can you explain?